# Cipher my friend sent me

Tags: cipher, pattern

> "The world is: ::: :#: : ::## :### / :##: ##: #:::"

My friend sent me it and said the use of the symbols : and # don't matter. It's the pattern that matters.

The hints he sent were:

> VI, 1, 1
> I, 17, 1
> III, 12, 1
> What hath God wrought?

(EDIT)
I worked it out.

> "What hath God wrought" is the official first Morse code message transmitted in the U.S...
>
> VI, 1, 1
> I, 17, 1
> III, 12, 1
>  This refers to the Enigma code.
>
>  With  ::: :#: : ::## :### / :##: ##: #::: > This part is Morse code, with "#" being "." and ":" being "-" > --- -.- - --.. -... / -..- ..- .---
>  This translates to OKTZB XUJ > OKTZB XUJ put through the Enigma code translates to delic ate...
> Ending in "The world is delicate."

Comment: The "what hath God wrought" is a good clue. Try Rot13(Zbefr Pbqr)

Comment: @Brandon_J Or it refers to rot13(Obbx bs Ahzoref) and the other clues point to there (puncgre, irefr, jbeq?) Plain interpretation of the code as zbefr pbqr does not seem to make sense.

Comment: Good call on the rot13(Obbx bs Ahzoref) reference. Not sure which translation the clue is referring to but if it's the rot13(xvat wnzrf irefvba) the key might be rot13(NAQ).

Comment: If you figure out the solution, please do not edit it into the question; you should post a [self-answer](/help/self-answer) instead.

Comment: This puzzle should be closed. I don't think the OP is coming back to post a self-answer.